# Guardar una imagen en tipo blob en oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy haciendo una consulta para subir imágenes que ya se encuentran en un servidor guardados pero las piden subir a la base de datos, entre los requisitos me piden que no se cree el directorio entonces estoy buscando forma de quitarlo o mandarlo a llamar en la consulta, espero me puedan orientar si esto se puede hacer, de antemano gracias

asi cree mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_BLOB (
    id NUMBER,
    valor BLOB DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB()
);
```

Cree mi directorio dir_temp, pero les menciono que es el que busco la forma de quitarlo , si se puede y marcar la ip sin necesidad de ocupar el directorio. Ocupo oracle sql developer version 19.2.1

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  --src_file varchar2(20);
  v_blob BLOB;
  v_bfile BFILE := '\\192.170.1.103'; 
BEGIN
--src_file := v_file('TEMP', DIR);
INSERT INTO TABLA_BLOB(id, valor) VALUES (8, EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING valor INTO v_blob;
  v_bfile := BFILENAME('DIR_TEMP ', '\2019_1\Entradas\Ent_Vol0001_2019\1\000K2OL1XE001Ktmp.jpg');
DBMS_LOB.OPEN(v_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(v_blob, v_bfile, SYS.DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_bfile));
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_bfile);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Cómo está definida la tabla? Qué versión de Oracle usas? Por favor ve a [edit] a pregunta y añade esta información

Comment: ya lo añadi, gracias